# Has Laravel 5.2 discontinued form model binding and helpers like Form::model?

Tags: laravel, model-binding

I cannot locate any official help on the Laravel 5.2 docs, and the only way to use Form::model, and Form::open in my apps using Laravel 5.2 seems to use LaravelCollective.

Any ideas on what is the current best practice for form model binding in Laravel's latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 5.0 [Laravel Collection HTML & Forms](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) became separated package which should be [installed with composer.](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#installation)

> If you're using Form or HTML helpers, you will see an error stating
>   class 'Form' not found or class 'Html' not found. The Form and HTML
>   helpers have been deprecated in Laravel 5.0; however, there are
>   community-driven replacements such as those maintained by the Laravel
>   Collective.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

Comment: Just an addition to your answer above. The link given is for version 5.1. I am using 5.2, and therefore was unable to install it if my JSON file was updated to 5.1.* instead of 5.2.*